# the people’s anxiety for the war (to end)

Tags: infinitives, to-infinitive

> "the people’s anxiety for the war to end"

> "the people's anciety for the war" means they want the war to happen ?

What's the function of 'to end' after for the war? Is there any difference with the sentence below?

"It's easy for you to solve this problem." : for + sb (and sb can solve)

I think 'the war' itself can't end something: it is a subject to be ended.

Why is there 'to end' after "for the war"?

Comment: _End_ here means _come to an end_. People are anxious for this to happen.

Comment: The sentence without "to end" means they want the war ?

Comment: Yes, being _anxious for something_ often means that you want it (see PPH's answer). Otherwise it's _anxious about_.

Comment: Is there any case that use other prepositions instead of 'for'?

Comment: Do you mean with _anxious_ or _anxiety_?  As the answer shows, you can use _to_ with the same sense as _for_. I can't think of any others.

Comment: i mean in the structure : for A to do B (what prepositon instead of for)

Comment: _I'm waiting for him to arrive_. No other preposition is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Your example comes directly from [Oxford Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/anxiety?q=anxiety), where what it means is clearly explained:

> [uncountable] a strong feeling of wanting to do something or of wanting something to happen
>
> - **anxiety to do something** *the candidate’s anxiety to win the vote*
> - *A couple of photographers fell over themselves in their anxiety to get a shot of her.*
> - **anxiety for something** *the people’s anxiety for the war to end*

As explained in comments by @Kate Bunting, "end" is a verb here.

So yes, it is similar to your example:

> *It's easy **for** you **to solve** this problem.*

Here are some more examples:

*You stop at the traffic lights and wait **for** the light **to turn** green.*

*Why was she so anxious **for** me **to stay**?* ([Longman Dictionary](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/anxious))

Comment: please post text as text, not images. People with screen readers, for example, won't be able to see what the image says.

Comment: @Esther. I also provided a link to the relevant dictionary entry, but no worries, give me a couple of minutes and I'll sort it out.

Comment: Is there any case that use other prepositions instead of 'for'?

Comment: Specifically "end" is an intransitive verb here, while the OP seems to think it is always transitive based on the (rather confused) remark "think 'the war' itself can't end something: it is a subject to be ended."